# getting new file added to subversion without updating whole folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

What I want to do is be able to add a file to my folder which is under Subversion source control in my local computer and then commit it. no problem up to here. On the server I want to get the new file using Subversion but without having to do an 'Update' to whole folder (which may update a bunch of unrelated files).

You see, if I make a change to an existing file - I go to the server mark that file and do 'SVN Update' (using TortoiseSVN) but if I added a new file on my local computer I have no way of just getting it to the server without doing 'SVN Update' on the whole folder

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add a filename to the `svn up` command even if that file doesn't exist in the folder yet (as long as it exists in the repository):

```
svn up newFile.txt
```

Edit: Using TortoiseSVN I *think* you go to "check for modifications" then click "Check repository", then right click -> "update" on the new file.

Comment: Great. both 'svn up' command and Your TortoiseSVN method worked perfectly